what does the function insert() do? Attempt to read property "ConnID" on bool
i was checking the affected_rows but i experience such bug from my model. my model code below
namespace App\Models;

use \CodeIgniter\Model;

class ContactModel extends Model {
    public function saveData($data)
    {
        $db= \Config\Database::connect();
        $builder = $db->table('message');
        $res = $builder->insert($data);
        if ($res->connID->affected_rows>=1) 
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


insert() returns a boolean, not an object.

what does the function insert() do? is it not to put data into the database. for you to check that you have to check for the affected rows, for the affected_rows functionality its when you return whether the rows have been affected or not, if yes then a success message and if not fail message and ask the user to attempt again. ie the bool its not for the insert instead its for affected_row function which is for the connID.

insert() returns true if the insert was executed successfully and false if was not, see Documentation
So if you want to show an error message depending on whether the data was put into the database or not, you could just use return $res; instead of the if .... If you want to use affectedRows() instead, you need to call this on the $db variable ($db->affectedRows()), not on $res.

thanks for steering me to the right direction, now i get the result i wanted. what i did i returned the res and render the error message to the view.

@Marleen why don't you post your comment as an answer with links to the docs? maybe you'll need to edit the Q a bit to make a good Q/A pair?

As a general best practice, I recommend always returning the generated id (when there is one) from all INSERT queries.  This way you can log or further reference the new record by its specific id. From UPDATE and DELETE queries, I return the number of affected rows.

If you try to INSERT a table record and it fails, unless you are engaging specialized handling, this will be a fatal error, right?  There is no need to check for success on an INSERT query.  See How to get insert id after save to database in CodeIgniter 4

insert() returns true if the insert was executed successfully and false if it was not, see the documentation here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CodeIgniter%5CDatabase%5CBaseBuilder::insert
So if you want to show an error message depending on whether the data was put into the database or not, you could just use return $res; instead of the if ....
If you want to use affectedRows() instead, you need to call this on the $db variable ($db->affectedRows()), not on $res.
Edit: Depending on what version of CodeIgniter 4 you're using, the default settings may cause it to show a "Whoops!" error page on production instead of returning false when there was a database error.
If you want insert to return false, make sure the DBDebug value in app/Config/Database.php is set to 'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),. With this setting, it will show a full database error in development mode, and return false in production mode.
